# PHP exec command

Tags: php, exec

I am working on a project where I have to defend the website against code injection. Is there a list with all shell commands which doesn't need the php exec function? So a list with shell commands that can be performed from php without the exec command?

Comment: All of them? You should never be shelling out if you can help it. Sometimes you need to to run proper applications, but for simple standard shell commands pretty much everything should be doable from PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to checkout [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) which has the security functionality you're looking for built in. It's very light weight and each part can be used mostly by itself.

Comment: I'd recommend Kohana over CodeIgniter personally. It's much better thought out and newer, too.

Comment: Good call. I don't use PHP any more (couple years back was my last round with PHP), but CodeIgniter was the up and coming of my era. Kohana looks pretty interesting however.